# How to output Chinese to a table in HTML using JavaScript in another file

Tags: javascript, html, chinese-locale

I have a web page, and that web page has a JavaScript saved in another file, that is loaded into the web page. When webpage is loaded, JavaScript will create a table, and then it will output something into the cells of the table.

However, when I want to output Chinese Character like: "你好"。 Things screwed up, like this： ��������

How do I solve this problem so I can output the Chinese character?

Figure out where the problem come from: I load strings from text file, and those strings will be output to table. And those strings, if are Chinese, are turned into question marks.

Trying Unicode:

Code where I get problematic strings:

```
function get_Audio_List()
{   
$.get(list_File, function(data, status){

    // Debug Output..
    ( (DEBUG)   ?   alert("DEBUG: Data: \n" + data + "\nStatus: " + status) :   (null) );

    // Get Data..
    audio_List = new String (data);



    // Log to Console..
    ( (LOG) ?   console.log("Audio List: Loaded")   :   (null)  );

});
}
```

Note the Dialog Box shown by 'alert' function also shows Question Marks like the one I posted. However, if I 'alert' a Chinese Text by giving its Chinese character directly like: `alert("编码");`. It works fine, and I think that's what you interpreted.

Comment: You have to put chinese encode.. Let me search...

Comment: Well you can put this meta tag: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> Try it idk if it will work. :/

Comment: Thanks i tried that long time ago.. It works if i put my code in html file.. however my code are existed outside of the html.. so it did not work for me..

Comment: Try it: http://ecmanaut.blogspot.ca/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html

Comment: @Ikillnukes it gives this lol: ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½  Decoder cause malform O.O..

Comment: You have to use unicode, this is the only solution. :P

Comment: I have a solution! :)

Comment: @Ikillnukes "You have to use unicode" How? Saving in UTF-8? For both .js and HTML? I already did that.. However.. the text I receieved from.. is loaded from a .txt file.. I tried to save that .txt into UTF-8.. but it didn't work for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can try this: http://chinesenotes.com/chinese_js/chinese_js_dojo.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>
<title>Dojo: Hello World!</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import "/dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";
@import "/dojo/dojo/resources/dojo.css"
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"
djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
</script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="helloButton">你好世界！</button>
</body>
</html>
```

You can get the source of this page: http://chinesenotes.com/chinese_js/js_examples/dojo_ex.html

Comment: It looks intresting but JS is a beast O.O.. I'll take a look at it.. thank you =)